# CSS Image zoom in on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I have managed to create a zoom in effect for image on hover. However the problem is that image is moving to the right bottom corner while mouse is over. I would like to zoom in to the center-center. How it possible?

I have tried to use `transform scale(1.1);` and it works for zooming in to the center-center but then transition effect doesn't work. So image is just jumps to 1.1 on mouse over and effect is not smooth anymore.

P.S. I am using Joomla and SP Page Builder

```
.sppb-col-md-3
{
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.hover03
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

          transition: all 1s ease;
}
.hover03:hover
{
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: can you show the example where the scale isn't working because it should work

Comment: Use transform again but add `transform-origin:center`

Comment: David's suggestion worked! Thank you!

Comment: No browser has needed prefixes for transition in many, many years.

Comment: The value of transform-origin is by default center, so not sure how the suggestion of @David is making this working ... try to share the full code

Comment: @mrwad because you’ve shown no effort in trying to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the transition to the element, img tag in your case, and the effect (ie transform: scale;) on :hover. Hope that helps!

Have a look at this working example:

https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/JwJzxg

```css
.img-outer {
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 300px;
      max-height: 300px;

    }

    .img-inner {
      position: relative;

    }

    img {
      transition: 0.5s ease; 
    }

    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="img-outer">
     <div class="img-inner">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300C/O 
      https://placeholder.com/" alt="image">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As links go dead, your link will become useless. Please post your example markup here and not use a third party site.

Comment: Well, technically the sample code should ideally be added as a snippet in the post.